# Реализация процентного распределения без начального значения

Tags: php, балансировка

Нужно реализовать процентное распределение трафика, между партнерами.
Допустим мы имеем 4 партнера(общее количество трафика не известно):
1 партнеру - 15%
2 партнеру - 25%
3 партнеру - 10%
4 партнеру - 50%
Пробовал реализовать это с помощью rand, но погрешность довольно большая.
Заранее спасибо, за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
  $COUNT = 20040;

  $priority = array(15, 25, 10, 50);
  $prioritySum = array_sum($priority);
  
  $traffic = array();
  $balance = array();
  
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($priority); ++$i)
  {
    $priority[$i] /= $prioritySum;
    $traffic[$i] = 0;
    $balance[$i] = 0;
  }
  
  for ($i = 0; $i < $COUNT; ++$i)
  {
      $arr = array_keys($balance, min($balance));
      $partherIndex = $arr[0];
      
      $balance[$partherIndex] += 1.0 / $priority[$partherIndex];
      $traffic[$partherIndex]++;
  }
  
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($priority); ++$i)
    printf("%d<br>", $traffic[$i]);
```

`$priority` содержит распределение в процентах трафика между партнерами

`$balance` служебный массив для учета трафика с учетом приоритета

`$traffic` содержит количество отданного трафика

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что нужно!